# Json Parsing for Login Api

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to pasrse the json login Api..where the login page contains Pinnumber and password.
 .. i want to login with these details and then want to go to registration page.. with the details from the Api.. can anyone help me in this

thanks in advance

Comment: On this where are you facing a difficulty?

Comment: @user244540 You need to parse JSON response or what you need? Have you tried any thing?

Comment: i doont know to parse the json feed

Comment: @user244540 Kindly go through this link. http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/ This will give you an idea about json parsing.

Comment: @Basil yes ... iam not getting the format of that feed... can you help me

Comment: @user244540 if you are finding too difficult, pls provide link for getting the JSON response or provide the JSON response. I'll try to solve that..

Comment: http://74.53.225.73/justpinme/api/apirequest.php?method=login&PinNumber=justpinme1&Password=justpinme1 ..This is the link

Comment: @user244540: Below I have posted one solution to parse that login api response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4289/discussion-between-user244540-and-basil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code below:

```
String response ="{\"0\":{\"SessionId\":\"zDQKMvGMWD4e9960e376988\"},\"memberdetails\":{\"Ident\":8,\"PinNumber\":\"justpinme1\",\"Password\":\"justpinme1\",\"EmailAddress\":\"justpinme1@gmail.com\",\"FirstName\":\"test1\",\"LastName\":123,\"Birthdate\":19860909,\"Gender\":\"female\",\"Country\":\"india\",\"PhoneNumber\":2147483647,\"PhotoThumb\":\"\",\"PhotoOriginal\":\"\",\"RegisteredDate\":\"2011-09-06 09:18:31\",\"RegisteredIp\":\"122.165.76.30\",\"RegisteredDeviceId\":22,\"LastSessionId\":\"hbS4JV9DNv4e99600c38390\",\"Status\":\"Active\",\"SessionId\":\"zDQKMvGMWD4e9960e376988\"}}";//Assign the response that are getting on the login api
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject   =   new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject forSessionId = jsonObject.getJSONObject("0");
            String SessionId = forSessionId.getString("SessionId");
            System.out.println("SessionId="+SessionId);
            JSONObject memberdetails    =    jsonObject.getJSONObject("memberdetails");
            System.out.println("Ident="+memberdetails.getString("Ident"));
            System.out.println("PinNumber="+memberdetails.getString("PinNumber"));
            System.out.println("Password="+memberdetails.getString("Password"));
            System.out.println("EmailAddress="+memberdetails.getString("EmailAddress"));
            System.out.println("FirstName="+memberdetails.getString("FirstName"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Down-voted due to lack of proper description. It is just a chunk of code, not an answer.